# How to add radio button group in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var text = "";
for (var x = 0; x < questions.length; x++)
{
    text += (x+1) + ". " + questions[x] + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("q").innerHTML = text;
```

I have an array of questions (size=5) and 5 arrays of answers for each questions.

```
var ans1 = ["answer","answer","answer","answer"];
var ans2 = ["answer","answer","answer","answer"];
var ans3 = ["answer","answer","answer","answer"];
var ans4 = ["answer","answer","answer","answer"];
var ans5 = ["answer","answer","answer","answer"];
var questions = ["q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "q5"];
```

With my code, I'm just displaying the 5 questions. I can't figure out how to insert a radio button group of answers for each questions. Help?

(I already did it on java but I can't convert it into javascript. I'm new to it :| )
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [In HTML, with Javascript, create new radio button and its text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430455/in-html-with-javascript-create-new-radio-button-and-its-text)

Answer (score 1):

We could keep answers in a two dimensional array. That way we could avoid using *eval* method. The first loop is on questions and the second loop is on answers. 
You can try the following approach:

```
var ans1 = ["answer","answer","answer","answer"];
var ans2 = ["answer","answer","answer","answer"];
var ans3 = ["answer","answer","answer","answer"];
var ans4 = ["answer","answer","answer","answer"];
var ans5 = ["answer","answer","answer","answer"];
var questions = ["q1", "q2", "q3", "q4", "q5"];

for (var x = 0; x < questions.length; x++)
{
    var number = x + 1;
    newp = document.createElement("p");
    newp.appendChild(document.createTextNode((number) + ". " + questions[x]));
    newp.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    var thisAnswers = eval('ans' + number);
    for(i in thisAnswers){
      var ans = thisAnswers[i];
      var label = document.createElement("label");
      var radio = document.createElement("input");
      radio.type  = "radio";
      radio.name  = 'answer' + number;
      radio.value = ans;
      label.appendChild(radio);
      label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(ans));
      newp.appendChild(label);
    }
    document.getElementById("q").appendChild(newp);
}
```

Comment: thanks! (it turned into a checkbox but i solved it)
another question, how can I check the radio button that is selected?

Comment: Sorry, updated it. Now it's radio box. radio.name  = 'answer' + i; needs to be radio.name  = 'answer' + number;

Comment: Your another question is not clear. Do you want to get the selected radio value using Javascript?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, so that I can check if the answer is correct.

Comment: document.querySelector('input[name = "answer5"]:checked').value this will give you the selected radio value.

Comment: really thank you!
this'll be the last i guess: I have a refresh button where the questions with their answers should be randomized (switch places/numbers). I can only randomize the questions by now, not the answers. Any clue?

Comment: You can use this shuffle method to randomize the elements. You need to use this function before the question loop to randomize the questions. Similarly use it before the answer (second) loop to randomize the answers.   function shuffle(arr) {
  for (i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      var temp = arr[i];
      arr[i] = arr[j];
      arr[j] = temp;
  }
  return arr;
}

Comment: The answers just randomize on the same place/number.
I can't randomize the answers with their responding questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create radio options by creating an 'input' element through the DOM

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
```

You can make a radio type input by setting the type attribute

```
input.type = "radio";
```

You can also set the value of your input

```
input.value = ans1[0];
```

Here's a fiddle for a closer look: https://jsfiddle.net/0gw1ar21/2/